# Como criar Scope no Laravel 5.4 com tabelas ligadas por meio de belongsToMany

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent, laravel-5.4, scope

A estrutura da tabela é essa:

```
pessoa
   id - integer
   nome - string

unidade
   id - integer
   nome - string

pessoa_unidade
   pessoa_id - integer
   unidade_id - integer
```

Tenho os modelos:

```
class Pessoa extends Model
{
    public function unidades()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Unidade', 'pessoa_unidade');
    }
}

class Unidade extends Model
{
    public function pessoas()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Pessoa', 'pessoa_unidade');
    }
}
```

Ou seja, uma pessoa pode participar de várias unidades e uma unidade pode ter várias pessoas;

Na tabela usuários padrão do `Laravel` temos:

```
users
   id - integer
   nome - string
   unidade_id - integer
```

Onde cada usuário tem sua unidade.

**[PROBLEMA 1]**

Como criar um *scope* para buscar somente as pessoas vinculadas de determinada unidade?

Tentei utilizando *GlobalScope*:

```
class UnidadeScope implements Scope
{
    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
        $model->unidades()->where('unidade_id', 1);
    }
}

class UnidadeScope implements Scope
{
    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
        $query->unidades()->where('unidade_id', 1);
    }
}
```

Mas não consegui... tentei utilizar *LocalScopes*:

```
public function scopeUn($query, $unidade)
{
    return $query->unidades()->where('unidade_id', $unidade);
}
```

Sem sucesso...

---

**[PROBLEMA 2]**

Outro ponto desta questão é ter a opção de enviar uma variável para o `scope` como no exemplo que fiz acima no *local scope* onde envio a `unidade_id` ($unidade) do usuário por meio do *`controller`*, utilizando `Auth::user()->unidade_id;`.

A expectativa era que no *controller*, o *Local Scope* retornasse todos as pessoas vinculadas ao usuário logado, como segue:

```
Pessoa::Un(Auth::user()->unidade_id)->get();
```

Alguém já conseguiu implementar algo do tipo?

Comment: Não precisa montar `scope` para isso ou então não entendi sua pergunta, veja ao buscar a unidade de código 1 já vai trazer as pessoas vinculadas pela relação muitos para muitos, não precisa fazer um `scope`, mas, se eu não entendi bem se poderia melhorar a sua pergunta?

Comment: Grande @VirgilioNovic! Obrigado pelo retorno meu amigo! Sei que dá pra fazer no controller, trazendo a unidade do usuário e a partir daí trazer as pessoas *$unidade = Unidade::find(Auth::user()->unidade_id);* e *$unidade->pessoas()->get()*, mas minha ideia é manter a lógica do controller mais clean e direta possível, exemplo, na função **getPessoas** trazer as pessoas **Pessoas::get();** e não ter de sempre vincular a Unidade, acho que seria ideal usar *Scope* nesse caso, somente acho, se conseguir vou tentar implementar assim, caso negativo, vou fazer via controller mesmo. Valeu!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui com a ajuda de nossa comunidade da seguinte forma:

```
public function scopeUn($query, $unidade_id)
{
    $query->whereHas('unidades', function ($query) use ($unidade_id) {
        $query->where('pessoa_unidade.unidade_id', $unidade_id);
    });
}
```

Utilizando:

```
Person::Un(Auth::user()->unidade_id)->get();
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43848347/how-to-create-scope-in-laravel-5-4-on-belongstomany-table-connection